# Как не учитывать регистр в регулярном выражении?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Нужно определить количество гласных букв в строке.

Пишу так:

```
string str = "Это вот такое предложение, в котором 16 гласных";
Regex regex = new Regex("а|у|о|ы|и|э|я|ю|ё|е");
int result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
   if (regex.IsMatch(Convert.ToString(str[i])))
   {
      Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(str[i]));
      result++;
   }
```

Выдает 15, потому как "Э" не учитывается. Как не учитывать регистр в подсчете?

Знаю, что есть модификатор i. Как его использовать в С#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используем опцию `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` для регулярного выражения:

```
string str = "Это вот такое предложение, в котором 16 гласных";
Regex regex = new Regex("а|у|о|ы|и|э|я|ю|ё|е", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
int result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    if (regex.IsMatch(Convert.ToString(str[i])))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(str[i]));
        result++;
    }
```

Comment: RegexOptions можно группировать, например: 

RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.что то еще

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать.

Answer (score 5):

Ну почему все задачи делать при помощи регулярок?

Пробуем по-простому, и заодно подсчитаем, во сколько раз получилось скорее:

```
class Program
{
    // так считается в вопросе
    static int CountWithRegex(string str)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex("а|у|о|ы|и|э|я|ю|ё|е", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            if (regex.IsMatch(Convert.ToString(str[i])))
            {
                result++;
            }
        return result;
    }

    static string vowelString = "ауоыиэяюёе";

    // множество гласных
    static HashSet<char> vowels =
                    new HashSet<char>(vowelString + vowelString.ToUpper());

    // так можно посчитать по-простому
    static int CountWithoutRegex(string str)
    {
        int result = 0;
        foreach (var c in str)
            if (vowels.Contains(c))
                result++;
        return result;
    }

    // удобная функция для подсчёта производительности
    static void TimeIt(Func<string, int> f, string arg, int repetitions, string name)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        // несколько повторений, чтобы исключить случайности
        for (int i = 0; i < repetitions; i++)
            sum += f(arg);
        sw.Stop();
        sum /= repetitions;
        if (name != null)
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: result = {1}, time = {2} ms",
                              name, sum, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = "Это вот такое предложение, в котором 16 гласных";
        // сделаем строку подлиннее
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            str += str;

        // прогреваем код, чтобы пробежал JIT
        TimeIt(CountWithRegex, str, 1, null);
        TimeIt(CountWithoutRegex, str, 1, null);

        // собственно измерение
        TimeIt(CountWithRegex, str, 1000, "with regex");
        TimeIt(CountWithoutRegex, str, 1000, "without regex");
    }
}
```

Программа выдаёт (Release mode, запущено без отладчика):

> with regex: result = 512, time = 902 ms
> without regex: result = 512, time = 67 ms

Итого: в ~13 раз скорее.

---

Даже если конструировать регулярку один раз и предкомпилировать её, получается лишь ненамного лучше:

```
static Regex regex = new Regex("а|у|о|ы|и|э|я|ю|ё|е",
                               RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
static int CountWithRegex(string str)
{
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        if (regex.IsMatch(Convert.ToString(str[i])))
        {
            result++;
        }
    return result;
}
```

Результат:

> with regex: result = 512, time = 819 ms
> without regex: result = 512, time = 68 ms

«Всего» в 12 раз скорее.